# Inno Setup ComponentsList OnClick event

Tags: delphi, inno-setup, pascalscript

I have a list of components for my Inno Setup installer, 19 different options, I want to set the `OnClick` event for **ONE** of the components. Is there a way to do this? Or is there a way to check which component triggered the `OnClick` event if it's set for all components?

Currently, the `OnClick` event is set like so:

```
Wizardform.ComponentsList.OnClick := @CheckChange;
```

I would like to do something like:

```
Wizardform.ComponentsList.Items[x].OnClick := @DbCheckChange;
```

The `WizardForm.ComponentList` is declared as a: `TNewCheckListBox`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not want to use `OnClick`, use `OnClickCheck` instead.

The `OnClick` is called for clicks which do not change checked state (like clicks outside of any item; or clicks on fixed items; or selection change using keyboard), but mainly it is not called for checks using keyboard.

The `OnClickCheck` is called only, when the checked state changes, and both for keyboard and mouse.

To tell which item was checked by user, use `ItemIndex` property. The user can check only the selected item.

Though if you have a components hierarchy, or setup types, the items checked automatically by the installer due to a change in child/parent items or change in the setup type, won't trigger the `OnClickCheck` (nor the `OnClick`). So to tell all changes, all you can do is to remember the previous state and compare it against the current state, when the `WizardForm.ComponentsList.OnClickCheck` or `WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange` are called.

```
const
  TheItem = 2; { the item you are interested in }

var
  PrevItemChecked: Boolean;
  TypesComboOnChangePrev: TNotifyEvent;

procedure ComponentsListCheckChanges;
var
  Item: string;
begin
  if PrevItemChecked <> WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[TheItem] then
  begin
    Item := WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemCaption[TheItem];
    if WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[TheItem] then
    begin
      Log(Format('"%s" checked', [Item]));
    end
      else
    begin
      Log(Format('"%s" unchecked', [Item]));
    end;

    PrevItemChecked := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[TheItem];
  end;
end;

procedure ComponentsListClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComponentsListCheckChanges;
end;

procedure TypesComboOnChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { First let Inno Setup update the components selection }
  TypesComboOnChangePrev(Sender);
  { And then check for changes }
  ComponentsListCheckChanges;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.ComponentsList.OnClickCheck := @ComponentsListClickCheck;

  { The Inno Setup itself relies on the WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange, }
  { so we have to preserve its handler. }
  TypesComboOnChangePrev := WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange;
  WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange := @TypesComboOnChange;

  { Remember the initial state }
  { (by now the components are already selected according to }
  { the defaults or the previous installation) }
  PrevItemChecked := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[TheItem];
end;
```

---

*For a more generic solution, see [Inno Setup Detect changed task/item in TasksList.OnClickCheck event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42173752/850848). Though with components, one has to trigger the check on the `WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange` call too.*

Answer (score 2):

> Or is there a way to check which component triggered the onclick event if it's set for all components?

Most component events have a `Sender` parameter to point at the component object that is firing the event.  However, in this case, the `Sender` will likely be the `ComponentsList` itself.  Depending on what `ComponentsList` is actually declared as (`TListBox`, etc), it may have a property to specify which item is currently being selected/clicked (`ItemIndex`, etc).  Or it might even have a separate event to report per-item clicks.  You did not say what `ComponentsList` is declared as, so nobody here can tell you exactly what to look for in it.

Comment: the list is a `TNewCheckListBox`