# Inno Setup Disable Next button when input is not valid

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I need to disable *Next* button, when input is not "Admin".

Something like:

```pascal
procedure EditKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  { enable the next button if the value in the box is admin; disable otherwise }
  WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled:=InputPage6.values[EditIndex2]‌​.Text = 'Admin'
end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement the input box `OnChange` event. You will also need to make sure the button state is updated, when the custom page is activated. You can use `OnActivate` event for that (or `CurPageChanged` event function).

```pascal
var
  Page: TInputQueryWizardPage;

procedure ValidatePage;
begin
  WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := (CompareText(Page.Values[0], 'Admin') = 0);
end;  

procedure EditChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ValidatePage;
end;

procedure PageActivate(Sender: TWizardPage);
begin
  ValidatePage;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  Page := CreateInputQueryPage(...);
  // To disable the Next button initially [when box is empty]
  Page.OnActivate := @PageActivate;
  Page.Add(..., False);
  // Update Next button state on any input change (typing, copy&paste, whatever)
  Page.Edits[0].OnChange := @EditChange;
end;
```

---

To combine multiple validations, see [Inno Setup Disable Next button using multiple validation expressions (when input value matches one of multiple values)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53761284/850848).

For other approaches, see:

- [Inno Setup - Create User Input Query Page with input length and format limit and use the input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34684128/850848),
- [Validate data on custom page when Next button is clicked in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56263983/850848).