# Inno Setup Disable Next button using multiple validation expressions (when input value matches one of multiple values)

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have this code working ...

```pascal
procedure ValidatePage;
begin 
  WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled :=
    (CompareText(InputPage6.Values[EditIndex2], 'Admin') <> 0);
end;

procedure EditChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ValidatePage;
end;

procedure PageActivate(Sender: TWizardPage);
begin
  ValidatePage;
end;
```

But I want to add more validations.

Example: If you have not allowed `EX12345` or `EX54321`.

```pascal
WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled :=
  (CompareText(InputPage6.Values[EditIndex2], 'EX12345') <> 0);
```

and

```pascal
WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled :=
  (CompareText(InputPage6.Values[EditIndex2], 'EX54321') <> 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking how to combine multiple logical expressions into one. Use [boolean operators](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu46.html), particularly `and` operator.

```pascal
procedure ValidatePage;
begin 
  WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled :=
    (CompareText(InputPage6.Values[EditIndex2], 'EX12345') <> 0) and
    (CompareText(InputPage6.Values[EditIndex2], 'EX54321') <> 0);
end;
```

Particularly if you are going to add even more options, you can optimize the code by storing the value into a local variable first:

```pascal
procedure ValidatePage;
var
  Value: string;
begin 
  Value := InputPage6.Values[EditIndex2];

  WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled :=
    (CompareText(Value, 'EX12345') <> 0) and
    (CompareText(Value, 'EX54321') <> 0);
end;
```