# Inno Setup: Force component to have always same check status as it's parent

Tags: inno-setup

My component section:

```
[Components]           
  Name: "client"; Description: "Client"; Types: full default monitor; 
  Name: "server"; Description: "Server"; Types: full default server; 
    Name: "server/feature"; Description: "Optional feature";   
    Name: "server/Db"; Description: "Always supported server feature"; Types: full default server; Flags: fixed
      Name: "server/Db/latest"; Description: "Latest"; Types: full default server; Flags: exclusive       
      Name: "server/Db/2_10"; Description: "2.10"; Flags: exclusive
```

I would like to have component **server/Db** that is always selected when its parent **server** is selected. I was able to acomplish it with **fixed** flag, but then I'm not able to select **server/Db/2_10**. If I tried to select second exclusive component, **server/Db** is unsellected altogether.
I can only select **server/Db/2_10** if **server/Db** isn't flaged as fixed, but then I'm able to unselect it.

**Edit:**
I added procedures like in [Inno Setup: how to auto select a component if another component is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47431511/2416941). Just changed **ComponentsListCheckChanges** procedure like this, (because I don't want to allow user to uncheck it):

```
procedure ComponentsListCheckChanges;
begin
  // No metter what you chceck/uncheck force component if needed.
  if WizardIsComponentSelected('server') then
  begin 
    WizardSelectComponents('server/Db');
  end
  else
  begin
    WizardSelectComponents('!server/Db');
  end
end;
```

I just found out, that If I try to uncheck **server/Db**, its checked back, that's good, but Type change to Custom even if it match other predefined type. Did I made some mistakes?

---

**Old:**
I also tried to mark it as Disabled in code. I was able to select both exclusive components, but not able to Uncheck component **server** anymore.

```
[code]
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectComponents then
      WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[3] := False;
end;
```

I'm able to create same behavior in component section as with code above by adding custom to Types list. I'm able to select both exclusive components, but can't uncheck **server**

```
[Components]           
  Name: "client"; Description: "Client"; Types: full default monitor; 
  Name: "server"; Description: "Server"; Types: full default server; 
    Name: "server/feature"; Description: "Optional feature";   
    Name: "server/Db"; Description: "Always supported server feature"; Types: full default server custom; Flags: fixed
      Name: "server/Db/latest"; Description: "Latest"; Types: full default server; Flags: exclusive       
      Name: "server/Db/2_10"; Description: "2.10"; Types: custom; Flags: exclusive
```

Last thing that I tried was setting it to True in code if **server** is checked. I Tried using code from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36989894/2416941 , it forced **server/Db** to behave like I wanted but, in dropdown menu above components, Selected Type stopped changing, It always showed as Default instalation and not Custom or any other type, so I don't think that's a valid solution.

How can I force **server/Db** to be always checked with **server** and able to choose one of **server/Db**'s children, and still possible to uncheck **server**?
Or is there other way to group exclusive components?

Comment: See [Inno Setup: how to auto select a component if another component is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47431002/850848)

Comment: This aproach stops Types from changing after checking/unchecking any components. It keeps last selected type, never changes to Custom or any other type that much selection.

Comment: I have edited the answer.

Comment: I didn't save that answer before, what did change that it now  update type?
I edited question and added my bersion of ComponentsListCheckChanges.
I found out, that If I try to uncheck server/Db, its checked back, that's good, but Type change to Custom even if it match other predefined type. Did I made some mistakes?  
Should I bother with this last thing or copy my ComponentsListCheckChanges to answer and mark it done?
If this last thing worked I think it would be perfect.

Comment: There's a link to any post revision history just below the post text -- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47431511/revisions

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about revisions history.
I had to call default OnClickCheck to Update Type selection after changing check status in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it works corectly by editing answers for [Inno Setup: how to auto select a component if another component is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47431511/2416941) but had to add **ComponentsListClickCheckPrev(nil);** to Update Type selection corectly after calling **WizardSelectComponents**.

```pascal
[Code]
var
  TypesComboOnChangePrev: TNotifyEvent;
  ComponentsListClickCheckPrev: TNotifyEvent;

procedure ComponentsListCheckChanges;
begin
  { If Check status of components is different }
  { Update child's status with parent's status. }
  if WizardIsComponentSelected('server') <> WizardIsComponentSelected('server/Db') then
  begin
    if WizardIsComponentSelected('server') then { If checked parent }
    begin
      WizardSelectComponents('server/Db'); { Check component }
    end
      else
    begin
      WizardSelectComponents('!server/Db'); { Uncheck component }
    end;
    ComponentsListClickCheckPrev(nil); { Update Type selection after my edits }
  end;
end;

procedure ComponentsListClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { First let Inno Setup update the components selection }
  ComponentsListClickCheckPrev(Sender);
  { And then check for changes }
  ComponentsListCheckChanges;
end;

procedure TypesComboOnChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { First let Inno Setup update the components selection }
  TypesComboOnChangePrev(Sender);
  { And then check for changes }
  ComponentsListCheckChanges;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  { The Inno Setup itself relies on the TypesCombo.OnChange and OnClickCheck. }
  { so we have to preserve their  handlers. }

  ComponentsListClickCheckPrev := WizardForm.ComponentsList.OnClickCheck;
  WizardForm.ComponentsList.OnClickCheck := @ComponentsListClickCheck;

  TypesComboOnChangePrev := WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange;
  WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange := @TypesComboOnChange;
end;
```